# How to find the Landing Page file in the Marketo by URL?

Tags: marketo

I work with [Marketo](https://www.marketo.com/) platform. In my account, in *Design Studio* there are a lot of created *Templates*, *Landing Pages* and other *Marketo objects*.

Does anyone know **how to find the *Landing Page* file in *Marketo*, knowing only its approved public *URL*?**

I would like to add that a *manual search* of the whole *Design Studio* is *not an option*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazing, I was unsuccessfully looking for a solution for several hours with my colleagues and when I wrote a question on *StackOverflow*, I found the answer very quickly...

**The solution:**

Just go to the *Design Studio* section, next in the left navbar click on *Landing Pages* branch. Then paste *URL* into *Quick Find* input, in the footer of right (main) site section. Then press Enter and *voilà*! We get a list of *fitted Landing Pages*.

**Path with solution on screen:**

[image]

**Hint:**

If you can not find the page, check if it is not in the archive:

[image]

Enjoy! :)

Comment: You are amazing man! It works! Even marketo forum didn't know this solution!

Comment: I read it few weeks ago. It's outdated (2014) and no more supported (have a look in the comments below).

Comment: Yes, you have right @PiotrKowalski, but I add there in a comment the link to this answer :)

Comment: Yes! Great answer. Searching for LPID on the page only works if there's a form on the page. Appreciate you posting this.